# calling a class from a class included in trigger

Tags: apex

I am very new in the apex developer world and have a question that I have a feeling might seem very generic... In my SF instance I have an opportunity master trigger that includes a class that handles all before and after events (`insert, update, and delete`).  My question is how can I call a class like this:

```
public PageReference InsertNewBacklogsAndRedirect(){

        try {
            if (Test.isRunningTest() && throwTestExceptions) {
                Integer lolmath = 1/0;
            }

            // Validate
            ValidationResult vr = ValidateGeneratable(opp);
            if (!vr.IsValid) {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, vr.ReasonMsg));
                return null;
            }

            Backlog__c[] newBacklogs = GenerateBacklogs(opp);
            insert newBacklogs;



        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.LogApexException(e, 'On BacklogGenerator visualforce page for Opportunity Id=' + opp.Id);
            ApexPages.addmessage(CommonLoggingUtils.ConvertExceptionToPageMessage(e));

            return null;

        } finally {
            log.Flush();
        }


    }
```

from the master class

```
public void OnAfterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newMap) {

        generate.InsertNewBacklogsAndRedirect();


    }
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Triggers cannot return page references, so I'm not sure why you'd try to do this?

Comment: Sorry, need to get rid of the page reference code.

Comment: You are also going to want to bulkify this a bit.  Your "InsertNewBacklogsAndRedirect()" method is assuming it's only looking at one record, but a trigger can be processing >1.  You'll either way to handle with a for() loop in the trigger, or (likely more scalable) in the Insert...() method itself

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty basic question: "how does a developer call one class from another?". But no matter, it is important and probably not trivial.

There are certainly a lot of questions as to the construction of the code itself, and following best practices, but let's get down to the root of the question.

I have class `ClassToCall`, and I want to invoke some functionality within it.

To add a Salesforce slant to it, we'll also fit your context: a trigger. And for fun, let's say we will get all the account name values for accounts with BillingCountry of Spain into a `List<String>` object to return. ("Why Spain?" you ask? "Why because that's where I am at the moment." I reply)

```
public class ClassToCall {

  public static List<String> actOnTriggerData(List<Account> triggerAccts){
    List<String> collectorList = new List<String>();
    for (Account a : triggerAccts){
      if (a.BillingCountry.equalsIgnoreCase('Spain')){
        collectorList.add(a.Name);
      }
    }
    return collectorList;
  }
}
```

Now, in your example class, I simply invoke this like so:

```
public void OnAfterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newMap) {

    List<String> nameStrings = ClassToCall.actOnTriggerData(newMap.values());

}
```

So what did I do?

First of all, I created a class. No big whoop there.

Second, I created a method. Some things about that method:

- I chose to make it static. If this is new to you, I'd recommend reading up on this. Static prevents you from instantiating an object (which is relatively expensive, resource-wise). There are a lot of trigger use cases where newer developers instantiate, when they don't have to. (In fact, your `onAfterInsert` method might be a candidate for this.)
- Next, I passed the data to the method that I wanted to act on. The method you are attempting to use, assumes there is a class-level property or attribute called `log`. In a VF controller, this makes sense, but in your case, you'll need to take the data that the trigger had ahold of (in `newMap`) and pass it to the method you want to invoke. In my case the line: `public static List<String> actOnTriggerData(List<Account> triggerAccts){` has the `triggerAccts` parameter. This is the hand off from the calling code (your trigger helper class) and the called code (my `ClassToCall`)
- Finally, there is the `collectorList` variable. You might say this is the "Saleforce-y" bit. But honestly this is just good coding practice: collect the stuff you want to act on into a separate collection. I used a very simple list-of-strings (`List<String>`) construct, but this can be any collection of any complexity. The first line inside my method I create the list. Inside the `for` loop I add to it (provided my `if` condition is met). Finally I `return` it and pass it back to the code that invoked it.

I agree with the commentor that you might need to proceed with caution with invoking `ValidateGeneratable` and `GenerateBacklogs`. If either of those performs any bulk-required operations (this would include saving, querying, searching, setting savepoints or performing rollbacks, or making callouts to external systems) you won't just be able to invoke them in the same fashion as they are invoked in the code you are attempting to use. This may require a full-scale refactoring of these methods, or at least bulkifying them.